# git merge заменяет текстовый файл вмсто слития

Tags: git, git-merge

Только начал изучать git

Создал ветку develop,в папке создал пустой файл txt,закомитил
Потом создал ветку feature/001,на которой в файл txt добавил условный текст "ааа",закомитил
Так же создал ветку feature/002 и feature/003 в которых соответственно редактировал файл txt и дописал там "bbb" и "ccc" и соответсвенно все закомитил
Мое ДЗ полагалось в том что бы я через merge их слил :

git checkout develop
git merge feature/001

здесь все нормально,в текством файле "ааа",но далее при

git merge feature/002

текст в файле вместо "aaa bbb"
просто удаляет "ааа" и заменяет его на "bbb"

Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы я через merge слил все ветки и в итоге в txt файле было "ааа bbb ccc"?

---

1. Создать ветку "develop", в ней создать файл 'topolia.txt "и закомитить этот файл.
2. Далее для каждой следующей из 5-ти действий создать новые ветви "feature / ..." и соответствующие комит.
3. С прикрепленного к заданию файла с стихом, скопировать 5 строчек в файл "Topolia.txt" и закомитить. Это действие повторить 5-ть раз. В каждой ветке этот файл должен содержать только по 5ть разных строчек.
4. Выполнить 'git merge' для ветви "develop" с вновь ветвями "Feature / ...". При этом, если возникнут конфликты, решить их. В результате мы должны иметь файл с 25 лентами

Comment: Приведите точную последовательность выполняемых вами команд, по словесному описанию много непонятного

Comment: Исходя из описанного содержания файлов - никак. Гит не будет добавлять первую и единственную строчку одного файла после первой и единственной строчки этого же файла в другой ветке. То, что один файл заменяется другим - ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: Выложите подучившийся репозиторий на гитхаб/гитлаб или ещё куда-нибудь

Answer (score 2):

Вы неверно представляете себе работу *Git*.  При
`git merge` он видит два состояния:

```
001 aaa
```

```
001 bbb
```

При `git merge`, *Git* не знает, какое из этих состояний
верное, поэтому, если вы действительно сделали ветки от одного и того же
коммита, у вас получится конфликт:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
aaa
=======
bbb
>>>>>>> feature/002
```

Если вы такого конфликта не видите, то ваша схема не соответствует тому,
что вы описали:

```
* merge feature/001 into develop (develop)
|\
| * aaa (feature/001)
|/
| * bbb (feature/002)
|/
* initial commit
```

---

После вашей правки, всё как раз так и есть.  У вас должны возникать
конфликты.  Решая их, *вы сами* должны оставлять все строчки.
Если я правильно понял задание, ваше дерево должно в итоге выглядеть
как-то так:

```
*   merge feature/005 into develop (develop)
|\      
* \   merge feature/004 into develop
|\ \      
* \ \   merge feature/003 into develop
|\ \ \    
* \ \ \   merge feature/002 into develop
|\ \ \ \  
* \ \ \ \    merge feature/001 into develop
|\ \ \ \ \
| | | | | *   eee (feature/005)
| | | | |/
| | | | /
| | | |/|
| | | / *   ddd (feature/004) 
| | |/|/
| | / /
| |/|/|
| / / *   ccc (feature/003)
|/|/|/
| / /
|/|/|
| / *   bbb (feature/002)
|/|/
| /
|/|
| *   aaa (feature/001)
|/
*   initial commit
```

Comment: Эта информация должна быть в вопросе, а не в двух скопированных комментариях.

Comment: извиняюсь,первый раз на сайте

Comment: @GiveMeGroove-_-  См. правку.

Answer (score 1):

> Потом создал ветку

Мы не создаём сферическую ветку в вакууме. Важно знать от какой точки в истории ветка создаётся. А создаётся ветка обычно от того места, куда указывает в данный момент указатель **HEAD**, если вы явно не указали, где создать ветку.

Судя по вашему описанию, вы забывали переместить **HEAD** обратно в **develop** и новые ветки создавали от вершины предыдущей тематической ветки. И не добавляли строки в изначальный пустой файл, а редактировали ранее измененный **topolia.txt**

```
o---o develop
     \
      o feature/001
       \
        o feature/002
         \
          o feature/003
```

В этому ваше слияние **git merge feature/00x** на самом деле ничего не сливает, а просто перемещает указатель **develop** на вершину **feature/00x** и повторяет изменение файла, когда вы **ааа** заменили на **bbb** и т. д. Тут нечему конфликтовать.

```
o---o develop
   /|\
  | | o feature/001
   \ \ 
    \ o feature/002
     \
      o feature/003
```

Если бы вы создали ветки правильно, то у вас бы возник конфликт. Когда в одном пустом файле добавили **aaa**, а в другом пустом файле добавили **bbb**. Вам бы пришлось разрешать конфликт и оставить обе строчки.